# How to solve quadratic equations with three variable?

Tags: quadratics, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

<sub>Previously [posted](https://mathoverflow.net/q/366188) at MathOverflow</sub>

---

Suppose we have $p$ quadratic equations
\begin{eqnarray}
    \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
         \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{C}_1 \mathbf{x} = 1,  \\
         \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{C}_2 \mathbf{x} = 1,  \\
         \quad\quad \vdots\\
         \mathbf{x}^\top \mathbf{C}_p \mathbf{x} = 1,  \\
     \end{array}
    \right.
    \label{eq:quadEqus}
\end{eqnarray}
where $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$, $\mathbf{C}_1 \sim \mathbf{C}_p \in\mathbb{R}^{3 \times 3}$ are positive definite symmetric matrices.

Suppose $\mathbf{x} = [a,b,c]^\top$, and $\mathbf{y} = [a^2,b^2,c^2, ab, ac, bc]^\top$, it is known that the above quadratic equations can be written as
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Ay} = \mathbf{1},
\label{eq:linearsolver}
\end{equation}
where $\mathbf{A} \in \mathbb{R}^{p \times 6}$. If $p \geq 6$, we can obtain $\mathbf{y}$ and further estimate $\mathbf{x}$.

**Questions**:

1. Is there any methods besides $\mathbf{Ay}=\mathbf{1}$ to solve the above quadratic equations?
2. What is the minimal value of $p$ to guarantee a unique solution of $\mathbf{x}$ of the above quadratic system?

Thanks.

Comment: There is no minimum value $p$ that guarantees a unique solution, for if $p = 1$, there are infinitely many solutions, while if $p = 2$, you can set $C_1 = I, C_2 = 4I$; the solutions to the two systems are then the unit sphere and the sphere of radius two, which have no points in common, so there is not a unique solution; indeed, there's no solution at all.

Comment: @JohnHughes Thanks, I agree that there is no unique solution. Do you think there's another method to solve the above quadratic equations besides using $\mathbf{Ay=1}$? In that case, if $\mathbf{A}$ is full rank, $p \geq 6$ can guarantee a unique solution for $\mathbf{y}$, from $\mathbf{y}$ to $\mathbf{x}$ there's a sign ambiguity left. But suppose we know $\mathbf{x} >0$.

Comment: I have no idea --- this isn't my area at all.

Comment: X-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/q/366188/91764